# Set multiple IE10 cookies for the same domain?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, cookiestore

I’m trying to install a cookie file from code on a client side machine.  I can tell using the lovely IECookiesView tool, or the less lovely Notepad, that the cookie file contains multiple cookies of different names for the same domain.

However if I try (from C#) to set a cookie using InternetSetCookieEx, then I only appear to be able to set one cookie per domain.

Is there a way to set multiple cookies?

Answer (score 1):

When using InternetSetCookieEx, you add one cookie at a time. You call it multiple times to add more than one cookie.

Having said that, InternetSetCookieEx only modifies the user's cookie store at the integrity level that it's run at; by default, Internet-zone tabs run at Low Integrity or AppContainer Integrity and as a consequence any cookies set by an application running at MediumIL will be ignored by that process.

For more information, see Q10 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx and read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx

Comment: Have you actually done this?  I have tried calling it multiple times with differently named cookies, and only the last one is present in the resulting file (as browsed from IE or shown in IECookiesView).

Comment: I haven't just tried it, I've also code-reviewed the WinINET code in question. I don't know what you mean by "Resulting file"; the proper way to see whether a cookie is set is to either call InternetGetCookie or issue a request and look at the headers using Fiddler or a similar tool. Did you remember to specify an EXPIRES so that your cookie is a persistent cookie rather than a session cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue I had was that I had missed off the trailing semicolon on the first cookie.  This meant that subsequent attempts to set cookies were ignored.